# Running tar -xvf with busybox:1.28 image

Tags: tar, kubernetes

I am trying to copy and *extract* the content of a .tar file into a minikube container, the copy part is working correctly, but not the extraction:

**deployment.yaml**

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/my_custom_theme
      name: shared-volume            
      
  initContainers:
    - name: init-customtheme
      image: busybox:1.28
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -rL /CustomTheme/custom_theme.tar /shared && tar -xvf /shared/custom_theme.tar']
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /shared
        name: shared-volume          
      - mountPath: /CustomTheme
        name: theme-volume
               
  volumes:
  - name: shared-volume
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: theme-volume
    configMap:
      name: customthemes-configmap
```

The relevant part is this:

```
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -rL /CustomTheme/custom_theme.tar /shared && tar -xvf /shared/custom_theme.tar']
```

Does anyone know why I am not able to extract the file content?

Comment: (1) Can you retrieve the error message(s)? (2) Are you running `tar` in the right directory?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the reply there is not error message as far I can see, yes because I did "&& ls  /shared/ > file.txt"  and then connected to the pod and look at the file.txt file content and there it was the custom_theme.tar file

Comment: I don't mean "is `/shared/custom_theme.tar` the right path?"; I mean "is the current working directory right when you run `tar`?". Maybe you should `cd` first.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski omg it was just that I don't get it LOL. I did           command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -rL /CustomTheme/custom_theme.tar /shared && cd /shared/ && tar -xvf custom_theme.tar &> file.txt']
 and it works lol

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't get it, do you want to provide an answer so that I can accept and upvote?

Comment: I'm not sure if your original command didn't extract to `/` maybe. I don't know such containers enough to tell, you may want to check if the files are also there. A good answer would say "in your original command `tar` successfully extracted to …" or "`tar` was denied access to …" or "it depends". I don't know what happened, so I cannot write a good answer yet. All I know is one should pay attention to the working directory of `tar` (or use `-C`).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks a lot once, again, everything is working nice :)